# Can postgres insert triggers and/or check be ran without inserting

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I would love to be able to validate objects representing table rows using the database's existing constraints (triggers that raise exceptions and checks) without actually inserting them into the database.

Is there currently a way one could do this in postgres? At least with `BEFORE INSERT` triggers and `CHECK`, I assume it makes no sense with `AFTER INSERT` triggers.

The easiest way I can think or right now would be to:

1. Lock the table
2. Insert a new row
3. If exception raise to the API / else DELETE the row and call it valid
4. Unlock

But I can see several issues with this.

Comment: Insert in a transaction and then rollback. However, if you have a need to check data without actually inserting data I'd question whether these should be triggers; perhaps they should be validations on the model.

Comment: Consider upgrading to a current version urgently. Postgres 9.4 has reached EOL in 2020 and is hopelessly outdated.

Comment: The transaction method is the best way to do this. For future reference though, if you are using [plpgsql triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) and `BEFORE INSERT` you can  `RETURN NULL` to prevent the `INSERT` from happening after you did a check on the incoming data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simpler way is to insert within a transaction and not commit:

```sql
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO tbl(...) VALUES (...);
-- see effects ...
ROLLBACK;
```

No need for additional locking. The row is never visible to any other transaction with default transacton isolation level `READ COMMITTED`. (You might be stalling concurrent writes that confict with the tested row.)

Notable side-effect: Sequences of `serial` or `IDENTITY` columns are advanced even if the `INSERT` is never committed. But gaps in sequential numbers are to be expected anyway and nothing to worry about.

Be wary of triggers with side-effects. All "transactional" SQL effects are rolled back, even most DDL commands. But some special operations (like advancing sequences) are never rolled back.

Also, `DEFERRED` constraints do not kick in. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html)

> `DEFERRED` constraints are not checked until transaction commit.

If you need this a lot, work with a copy of your table, or even your database.

Strictly speaking, while any trigger / constraint / concurrent event is allowed, there is no other way to "validate objects" than to insert them into the actual target table in the actual target database at the actual point in time. Triggers, constraints, even default values, can interact with the current state of the whole DB. The more possibilities are ruled out and requirements are reduced, the more options we might have to emulate the test.

Comment: Oh yeah, in hindsight this is a much better approach given that the transaction would still leave the rest of the table readable until it ends but not the newly inserted row.

Comment: Though I guess it might still be more heavy-weight than the preferred solution that never writes if one exists(?) for the aforementioned reason of triggers with side effects, though not an issue in my case per-se.

Comment: @George: `the preferred solution that never writes if one exists(?)` If what exists?

Comment: if such a solution (i.e. one that doesn't write to the database) exists. Odd phrasing, sorry

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION validate_function ( )
 RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql
 
AS $function$
DECLARE
    valid_flag boolean := 't';
BEGIN
    --Validation code
    if valid_flag = 'f' then
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'This record is not valid id  %', id
        USING HINT = 'Please enter valid record';    
        RETURN NULL;
    else
        RETURN NEW;
    end if;
END;
$function$

CREATE TRIGGER validate_rec BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON some_tbl
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION validate_function();
```

With this function and trigger you validate inside the trigger. If the new record fails validation you set the `valid_flag` to `false` and then use that to raise exception. The `RETURN NULL;` is probably redundant and I am not sure it will be reached, but if it is it will also abort the insert or update. If the record is valid then you `RETURN NEW` and the insert/update completes.